# Flask debugger not appearing in browser

Tags: debugging, flask

I'm trying to use the flash debugger, where I made a mistake on purpose to test out the debugger. Whenever the error is shown it is only shown in the terminal, and I can't access the localhost to test it.

I have

```
 app.debug = True
```

But it only shows the stack trace in the terminal when I run.

```
flask run
```

when I run

```
python routes.py
```

I see the line where the error happened.

But how can I see the interactive debugger in the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable `FLASK_ENV=development`

This seems to be the suggested way to enable interactive debugging and other nice to have development features when using the `flask run` command.

Alternatively you can set `FLASK_DEBUG=1` to just enable the interactive debugger